# How to replace malloc with new in example

Tags: c++, malloc, msdn

I'm following a C++ msdn reference for Managing IP Addresses. The memory allocation in the example is using malloc instead of new. It is my understanding that malloc should never be used in C++. How would I go about converting these malloc's into new ?

Link: [MSDN REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The code in question:

```
MIB_IPADDRTABLE  *pIPAddrTable;
DWORD            dwSize = 0;
DWORD            dwRetVal;

pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*) malloc( sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE) );

if (GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
{
    free( pIPAddrTable );
    pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE *) malloc ( dwSize );
}

if ( (dwRetVal = GetIpAddrTable( pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0 )) != NO_ERROR )
{ 
    printf("GetIpAddrTable call failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
}

printf("IP Address:         %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwAddr);
printf("IP Mask:            %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwMask);
printf("IF Index:           %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwIndex);
printf("Broadcast Addr:     %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwBCastAddr);
printf("Re-assembly size:   %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwReasmSize);

if (pIPAddrTable)
    free(pIPAddrTable);
```

Comment: Instead of using `new[]`, in _modern C++_ you should use [a proper RAII container like `std::vector`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15690742/1629821).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not replace these uses of `malloc` with a *new-expression* because they do not initialise the object as `new` would. Instead, they pass the pointer to allocated memory to `GetIpAddrTable`, which appears to do the initialisation instead.

However, there is a C++ version of `malloc` which only does memory allocation: `operator new`. I'll pair up the lines with their replacements:

```
pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*) malloc( sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE) );
pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*) ::operator new( sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE) );

pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE *) malloc ( dwSize );
pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*) ::operator new( dwSize );
```

The uses of `free` will also need to be replaced with the deallocation function `operator delete`:

```
free( pIPAddrTable );
::operator delete(pIPAddrTable);
```

Comment: would pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*) = new char [dwSize]; Also work? and then delete [] pIPAddrTable;

Answer (score 3):

If you want to re-write that original C-style code using *modern C++*, you should use 
**`std::vector`** instead of `new[]` (and `malloc`).

`std::vector` is very convenient, e.g. it will automatically release its memory thanks to its destructor (also in case of exceptions thrown), it can be resized, etc.

This is an example of the above code, which uses `std::vector` instead of `malloc` and `new[]` (see the comments in the code for further details):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>       // for std::vector

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

int main()
{
    // Use std::vector to dynamically allocate memory.
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer(sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE));
    MIB_IPADDRTABLE * pIPAddrTable = reinterpret_cast<MIB_IPADDRTABLE*>(&buffer[0]);

    DWORD dwSize = 0;      
    if ( GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )
    {
        // Resize buffer to proper size
        buffer.resize(dwSize);        

        // Buffer memory can be re-based after allocation, so update base pointer
        pIPAddrTable = reinterpret_cast<MIB_IPADDRTABLE*>(&buffer[0]);
    }

    DWORD dwRetVal;   
    if ( (dwRetVal = GetIpAddrTable( pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0 )) != NO_ERROR )
    { 
        printf("GetIpAddrTable call failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
    }

    printf("IP Address:         %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwAddr);
    printf("IP Mask:            %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwMask);
    printf("IF Index:           %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwIndex);
    printf("Broadcast Addr:     %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwBCastAddr);
    printf("Re-assembly size:   %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwReasmSize);

    //
    // No need to cleanup memory:
    // std::vector destructor will do that for us automatically :)
    //    
}
```

(Note that `printf()` could be substituted with `std::cout`, but it's not as important as using `std::vector` instead of `malloc` or `new[]`.)